# Artin 12.M.3: $A^p=I$ where $A\in \mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z})$, show $n\geqslant p-1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

> **Artin 12.M.3**
>
> Let $p$ be an integer prime, and let $A$ be an $n\times n$ integer matrix such that $A^p = I$ but $A \not = I$.
> Prove that $n \geqslant p - 1$. Give an example with $n = p -1$.

Any ideas on how to prove this?

I noticed how $A^p-I=0$ implies $(A-I)\cdot (A^{p-1}+A^{p-2}+\ldots+A+I)=0$ but since $\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is not a domain, it will contain zero divisors. Then I can't conclude anything from these factors, not?

Also I have no idea on a proof-technique to tackle this problem. Assume $n<p-1$ and obtain a contradiction, but how?

In Artin's Algebra it is an exercise following the chapter on factoring which touches the Eisenstein Criterion. It seems somehow related but not quite...

#### Example

I've found an example where the result hold, but that didn't help on getting a better grip on the issue.

Let $p=3$ and $n=2$, then consider
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$
then $A^2=I$.

#### Edit, expansion of carmichael561 's answer

Let $PAP^{-1}$ be the diagonalization of $A$. Then $PAP^{-1}=\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n)$ and since $A\not = I$ then $\mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n)\not = I$.

Now consider $(PAP^{-1})^p = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1^p, \ldots, \lambda_n^p)$. And since $(PAP^{-1})^p = PA^p P^{-1} = I$ it follows that $\lambda_i$ is a $p$-th root of unity.

Now consider the charaterisitc equation of $A$, $\chi(x)$. Then $\chi(x)$ will be of degree $n$. The minimal polynomial $\mu(x)$ must have degree $\leq n$.

The degree of $\mu(x)$ will be $\leq p$ since $\mu(x) = x^p-1$ contains all possible $p$-th roots of unity. I don't see why it is not possible for the degree to be exacty $p$. If $A$ would have all different $p$-th roots of unity as eigenvalues then wouldn't the degree of $\mu(x)$ be exactly $p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Z})$ with $A^p=I$. Then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $p$th roots of unity, and if $A\neq I$ then at least one of eigenvalues must be a primitive $p$th root of unity, and therefore has a minimal polynomial (over $\mathbb{Q}$) of degree $\phi(p)=p-1$.

On the other hand, the eigenvalues of $A$ are roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which has integer coefficients and degree $n$. It follows that $n\geq p-1$.

Comment: It seemed clear, but some confusion still remains. Why is it impossible for $A$ to have all the different $p$th roots of unity as eigenvalues? Then the degree of the minimal polynomial would be $p$ right? As a extra question, I don't really see where the fact that $p$ is prime is being used? Is it because for $p$ not prime, there could be two $p$th roots of unity which are real?

Comment: The fact that $p$ is prime is being used in two ways: first, all the $p$th roots of unity besides $1$ are primitive $p$th roots of unity, and second, $\phi(p)=p-1$.

Comment: I've updated the question to pinpoint the exact problem. I know that if $\lambda_i$ has order $p$ (i.e. $\lambda_i^p=1)$ with $p$ prime, then there are $\phi(p)$ other $\lambda_i$ with the same order $p$. But I don't see the connection... I don't see why $A$ couldn't have all the different $p$-roots of unity, which would imply $\mathrm{deg}(\mu(x)) = p$ not?

Comment: The minimal polynomial of $A$ is not used in my answer. Instead, I argued that $A$ must have a primitive $p$th root of unity $\lambda$ as an eigenvalue, that the minimal polynomial of $\lambda$ has degree $p-1$, and that since $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ we must have $n\geq p-1$.

Comment: All clear! The reasoning uses $(x^p-1) = (x-1)(x^{p-1}+\ldots+x+1)$. Thanks!